# Clear "Recent Plays" list in Xbox Music

Tags: xbox-music

How do I clear (delete) the "Recent Plays" list in Xbox Music on my Nokia Lumia 928 with Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 2):

The Xbox Music app has just (21 April 2015) been updated to include the ability to remove items from the Recent Plays list. See [here](http://xboxmusic.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/559974-music-on-windows-phone-8-1-update-now-available) for the official announcement.

Comment: Shoot. I just realized that and came here to answer ;)